# Adding 1 hour to calendar Date doesn´t add the hour

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a Calendar object I set a Date as this:

```
calendarObject.setTime(date);
```

date is a Date object, I print date object and have the date I want: Sun Oct 31 02:00:00 CEST 2021

Then i want to add 1 hour to that calendar object that has my date object with 31/10/2021 02:00:00 so I do that:

```
calendarObject.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
```

I print again the calendarObject with:

```
System.out.println(calendarObject.getTime());
```

And shows again Sun Oct 31 02:00:00 CEST 2021 but I want to have Sun Oct 31 03:00:00 and I don´t know why it doesn´t work

SOLVE:
The problem was that the timezone the day 31 october at 3AM rolled back to 2AM,(hour change in that day at that hour) so It was adding 1 hour but at 3AM the hour changes again to 2AM.

Comment: 1 hour after Oct 31, 2 AM is Oct 31 2 AM. It's a time loop ... uhm, no, it's when summer time ends and the clocks fall back.

Comment: I'm just going to put this out there ... WHY are you still using `Calendar`?!  It's time (pun intended) to move on to the much improved and updated `java.time` API which would allow you get over these issues

Comment: so the problem is that I´m adding 1 hour but is detecting that is when the hour changes because of the summer so it keep the same hour because I´m adding 1 but the system is subtracting also 1 hour? @JoachimSauer

Comment: At 3 AM on October 31st, the time in that timezone will be rolled back to 2AM. I.e. It's 2AM **the second time on that day**. That's how daylight savings time transitions work (this or they leave a 1-hour gap in the day). Try adding 1 hour **again** and you see that it moves on now ... And yes, I agree with @MadProgrammer: use `java.time`, it's a **much** saner API.

Comment: Yes, solve, the problem was what you all are saying...  at 3AM the timezone rolled back, I have solved in a easy way to check, now I will do with java.time, thank to all!!

Comment: @JoachimSauer now I need that if I add 1 hour to the calendar and its 31 october 02:00 and adds one hour to stay again in 02:00, I have as in the post, with calendar and calendar.add(Calendar.minutes,60) but it shows 03:00 any idea why now it doesn´t return to 02:00?

Comment: @wty: post a new question with an [mre] about what you're doing. There's *so many* ways this could be going wrong that we can only just guess unless you show the **exact** code that you run  and that belongs into a new question.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

Like others I warmly recommend java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(
            2021, 10, 31, 2, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
    System.out.println(dateTime);

    dateTime = dateTime.plusHours(1);
    System.out.println(dateTime);

    dateTime = dateTime.plusHours(1);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> ```
> 2021-10-31T02:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
> 2021-10-31T02:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
> 2021-10-31T03:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
> ```

Please substitute your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be Europe/Berlin. CEST is the common abbreviation used during summer time (DST) for a long list of Arctic, European and African time zones being at offset +02:00 during summer time (most of them at +01:00 during standard time).

As others have also said, in the night between October 30 and 31 this year, most of the mentioned time zones transitioned from summer time to standard time. When the clocks were about to be 03:00, they were instead turned back to 02:00. So when you add an hour to 02:00 (summer time) you should get — well, 02:00 (standard time). In the output above you can distinguish in that summer time uses offset +02:00 and standard time uses +01:00. From 02:00 standard time time moves forward as usual. Until March, and the insanity repeats, only opposite. When we add one further hour, we do get 03:00 standard time as expected.

Link: [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) showing the use of java.time.